# urlretrieve generating "No such file" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the problem below:

```
objectlist = ["1", "2", "3"]
namelist = ["name1.png", "name2.png", "name3.png"]    

for i in objectlist:
    for j in namelist:
    url = "https://your.domain/id="+i
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, j)
```

I need to access the URL in the sequence "1", "2" and "3" and download the renaming PNG images according to "name1.png", "name2.png" and "name3.png". However, I get this error:

```
    CeXs-MacBook-Air:Report Graphics danielvincenzi$ python3 main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
        download(objectid, nameid)
      File "main.py", line 53, in download
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, j)
      File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 258, in urlretrieve          
        tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'name1.png'
```

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using, or are there directories in front of the filenames in your actual code? Because I can reproduce that error by attempting to `urlretrieve` to a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, please be careful to verify that Python code you paste into a question is properly formatted (indented). It can be difficult to tell if someone's issue is caused by improper indentation or if they just pasted it in wrong.

Comment: Do directories of the filename exist locally?

Comment: I have a real code behind this one, but it contains information that I can not show and I used this as an example.

Comment: I believe the error is when I name the file saved by the variable... urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, j)

Comment: It is saving the file directly to the project folder.